# Deciding the convexity of semialgebraic sets

Tags: convexity, real-algebraic-geometry

Given a basic closed [semialgebraic set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semialgebraic_set), $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, defined by

$S = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid g_1 (x) \geq 0 \land \dots \land g_m (x) \geq 0\}$

where $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $g_1, \dots, g_m \in \mathbb{R}[x]$, how can one decide if $S$ is convex? Some context: this question arose while reading [Schweighofer](http://www.math.uni-konstanz.de/~schweigh/)'s slides on [LMI representations of convex semialgebraic sets](http://www.math.uni-konstanz.de/~schweigh/presentations/dcssblmi.pdf) [pdf].

Let us introduce the predicate $p (x) = \bigwedge_{i=1}^m g_i (x) \geq 0$, so that we can write $S$ in the more parsimonious form $S = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid p (x)\}$. From [Boyd & Vandenberghe](http://www.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/), we have the following definition:

> A set $C$ is *convex* if the line
>   segment between any two points in $C$
>   lies in $C$, *i.e.*, if for any $x_1,
> > x_2 \in C$ and any $\theta$ with $0 \leq \theta \leq
> > 1$, we have $\theta x_1 + (1-\theta)
> > x_2 \in C$.

Hence, $S$ is convex if and only if the following universally quantified formula

$\forall x_1 \, \forall x_2 \, \forall \theta \, \left[\, p(x_1) \land p(x_2) \land (\theta \geq 0 \land \theta \leq 1) \implies p (\theta x_1 + (1-\theta) x_2) \, \right]$

where $x_1, x_2$ range over $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\theta$ ranges over $\mathbb{R}$, evaluates to *true*. The formula above can be decided using a quantifier elimination package like [QEPCAD](http://www.usna.edu/cs/~qepcad/B/QEPCAD.html) or [REDLOG](http://redlog.dolzmann.de/).

**Question:** other than quantifier elimination, is there any procedure that would allow one to decide the convexity of a given basic closed [semialgebraic set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semialgebraic_set)?

Comment: This problem is no easier than deciding whether a given convex basic closed semialgebraic set is contained in a given arbitrary basic closed semialgebraic set, which seems like it would require quantifier elimination to solve. (If $f_i(x)\geq 0$ are the equations that define the first set and $g_j(x)\geq 0$ are the equations that define the second, then $f_i(x)\geq0\wedge g_j(x)+y^2\geq 0$ define a set that is convex if and only if the first is contained in the second.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [this paper by Ahmadi et al](http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2010/12/2846.pdf) the authors show that a very special case of this question (whether a polynomial is convex, so the set is the epigraph) is NP hard in many cases, so no really easy algorithm is likely to exist.

Comment: Thanks. I am, indeed, acquainted with Ahmadi's work on deciding the convexity of polynomials. Just like *some* nonnegative polynomials accept sum of squares decompositions (which can be found "efficiently" using semidefinite programming), my hope was that *maybe* one could decide the convexity of a certain class of semialgebraic sets using some sort of "trick". An algebraic certificate of non-convexity, akin to the Positivstellensatz, would be interesting, too. But, alas, I have never heard of a Konvexitätsatz!